# Identify intervals with certain values

Tags: python, dictionary, intervals

I'm new to Python and am stuck trying to identify "intervals" where y-value =< 70. I have an ordered dictionary entry:

```
 d = {0: '92', 11: '70', 43: '77', 44: '76', 61: '77', 64: '69',
                    68: '67', 84: '68', 93: '87', 108: '81', 141: '74'}
```

I want to write a function that allows me to identify "intervals" (a,b) based on the keys (x-values) of d based on y-values =< N.  My endpoints (a,b) should be where values start descending and ascending in and out of this N value, so the actual endpoint values would be "above" N but the entries between should be below.

```
 (a,b): {above, below, below, below, above}
```

For example I'm interested in the intervals as a dictionary, here N = 70:

```
{(0,43):{92,70,77}, (61,93): {77, 69, 67, 68, 87}} <-- includes the values at endpoints
```

But, can ignore those other "intervals" where the values are never lower than 70
 so in this case we don't need: (43,51), (93,180)

Is there a simple way to do this? So far, I've been able to identify the points where the change from "above" to "below" 70 or vice-versa occurs but not sure how to proceed in creating the intervals and values (such as in a dictionary). I think I've been staring at this for too long.

Comment: The example output uses y-value <= 70, not y-value < 70

Comment: Thanks! That was a typo.

Comment: ok, updated my answer accordingly

Comment: I just edited my answer again and the accept sign disappeared. Did you remove it? (I'm just curious to understand if editing removed it, I'm quite new here)

Comment: I'm fairly new! I accepted it by mistake when I was copying the text. I appreciate the help!

Comment: You say 'I have an ordered dictionary entry'. No you don't (:  Dictionaries are not ordered, they are like a hash table.

Comment: Yes, but i use the sorted() function to have it do that as i iterate through the keys. But thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should give you the output you asked for:

```
oninterval = False
dd = {}
keys = d.keys()
keys.sort()
start_key, first_val = keys[0], d[keys[0]]

for k in keys:
    v = float(d[k])
    if oninterval:
        cur_list.append(v)
        if not int(v) <= 70: # interval ends
            oninterval = False
            dd[(start_key,k)] = cur_list
    else:
        if int(v) <= 70:
            cur_list = [first_val, v]
            oninterval = True
        else:
            start_key, first_val = k, v

if oninterval: dd[(start_key, keys[-1])] = cur_list
```

Edit:

Extended code fraction to accept first or last item to have y-value <= 70 and to treat y-values as floats

Comment: This looks like how I started to write this loop so it's close to my logic. Thank you for making this long day a bit shorter.

Comment: If I feed this a new dictionary d, say d = {0: '78', 35: '61.33330154', 172: '65', 110: '59.66669846'}, then the output is {(141, 0): [74.0, 69.0, 78.0]}. Not sure why this is happening, but that (141,0) is something weird. Perhaps it's an issue with the meta-endpoints. For instance, I have x values from 0 to 180, so what happens when there is a low point right at the edge as I do here at 172 (value is 65)?

Comment: In the case where I would have to extend this output of (0,172) to (0,180), where should I modify the code? Thanks!

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean. Given the d = {0: '78', 35: '61.33330154', 172: '65', 110: '59.66669846'}, what output would you like?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8653/discussion-between-lillian-milagros-carrasquillo-and-kyss-tao)

Comment: Not sure why I'm getting this output now? d= {0: 78.0, 35: 61.33330154, 172: 65.0, 110: 59.66669846}; Output = 
{(0, 0): [74.0, 69.0, 78.0], (0, 172): [78.0, 61.33330154, 59.66669846, 65.0, 100.3330002]} Where is the 0,0 coming from?

Answer (score 3):

For reasons I cannot completely explain, this problem has mesmerized me. But I think I've finally gotten it out of my system. First, a basic, clean and simple solution:

```
intervals = [[]]
prev = None
sorted_items = sorted(d.iteritems())
for k, v in sorted_items:
    if v <= 70:
        ext = (k,) if (intervals[-1] or prev is None) else (prev, k)
        intervals[-1].extend(ext)
    elif intervals[-1]:
        intervals[-1].append(k)
        intervals.append([])
    prev = k

if not intervals[-1]:
    intervals.pop()

print dict(((iv[0], iv[-1]), [d[k] for k in iv]) for iv in intervals)
```

It's easy enough to abstract the above to create an iterator:

```
def iter_intervals(vals, filter_f, _nil=object()):
    prev = _nil
    interval = []
    for x in vals:
        if filter_f(x):
            ext = (x,) if (interval or prev is _nil) else (prev, x)
            interval.extend(ext)
        elif interval:
            interval.append(x)
            yield interval
            interval = []
        prev = x
    if interval: 
        yield interval

intervals = iter_intervals(d.iteritems(), lambda x: x[1] <= 70)
print dict(((iv[0][0], iv[-1][0]), [v for k, v in iv]) for iv in intervals)
```

But that has to store a lot of state. I wonder if there's a way to do less of that...

```
def iter_intervals(vals, filter_f, _nil=object()):
    iters = itertools.tee(itertools.chain((_nil,), vals, (_nil,)), 3)
    next(iters[1]); next(iters[2]); next(iters[2])
    triplets = itertools.izip(*iters)
    interval = set()
    for p, curr, n in triplets:
        if filter_f(curr):
            interval.update((p, curr, n))
        elif interval:
            interval.discard(_nil)
            yield sorted(interval)
            interval = set()
    if interval:
        interval.discard(_nil)
        yield sorted(interval)

intervals = iter_intervals(d.iteritems(), lambda x: x[1] <= 70)
print dict(((iv[0][0], iv[-1][0]), [v for k, v in iv]) for iv in intervals)
```

Having done that, now it's more obvious how to adapt [ninjagecko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9611560/577088)'s solution to avoid the lookahead/lookbehind problem that forced it to store a list:

```
def framed_intervals(points, filter_f, _nil=object()):
    iters = itertools.tee(itertools.chain((_nil,), points, (_nil,)), 3)
    next(iters[1]); next(iters[2]); next(iters[2])
    triplets = itertools.izip(*iters)
    for below, group in itertools.groupby(triplets, lambda x: filter_f(x[1])):
        if below:
            interval = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(group))
            interval.discard(_nil)   # or continue if None in interval to
            yield sorted(interval)   # drop incomplete intervals

intervals = framed_intervals(d.iteritems(), lambda x: x[1] <= 70)
print dict(((iv[0][0], iv[-1][0]), [v for k, v in iv]) for iv in intervals)
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I will be checking how this works later today myself. I too am a bit obsessed with this problem! It seems like a fairly common issue since all I'm doing is identifying intervals and am surprised to not find a module that covers this.

Comment: Ok, this is making sense to me and all examples I give it seem to be working. I'm having trouble adapting it in one particular case if the last value is <=70, the interval should be extended to the end of the x-values (that is if n=180 and d[id][last] <70 and last < 180, the interval output should be (a,180) not (a,last). For a real example:d['150','172'] = {73,55,55} then it really should be that the interval is (150,180) instead (where 180 is the max x-value).

Comment: @LillianMilagrosCarrasquillo, I don't totally follow. What's the `a` above? Show me an input dict/sequence that causes the problem, and the output you expect. Also, I did notice an error in the third version; I forgot to discard the `_nil` sentinel.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {0: '92', 11: '70', 43: '77', 44: '76', 61: '77', 64: '69',
        68: '67', 84: '68', 93: '87', 108: '81', 141: '74'}

r = []
k = None
v = None

for i in sorted(d.keys()):
    if not k is None:
        v.append(d[i])

    if int(d[i]) > 70:
        if k is None:
            k = [i]
            v = [d[i]];
        else:
            k.append(i)
            r.append((tuple(k), v))
            k = None
            v = None

print r
```

Comment: This is great! I knew there was a simple way I wasn't seeing after spending too much time at the computer.

One question: is there a way to handle d as a dictionary as in my example, or should I work to convert it to tuples? I have the data in a dictionary right now.

Comment: When I run this it prints `[[(0, 92), (11, 70), (43, 77)], [(44, 76), (61, 77)], [(93, 87), (108, 81)]]` but shouldn't the result be `[[(0, 92), (11, 70), (43, 77)], [(61, 77), (64, 69), (68, 67), (84, 68), (93, 87)]]`?

Comment: @LillianMilagrosCarrasquillo I've made it work with a dictionary now. Also you get the output as described in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a somewhat verbose solution:

```
import collections

values = [(0, '92'), (11, '70'), (43, '77'), (44, '76'), (61, '77'), (64, '69'),
   (68, '67'), (84, '68'), (93, '87'), (108, '81'), (141, '74')]
d = collections.OrderedDict(values)

def intervals(d, n):
    result = collections.OrderedDict()
    interval = list()
    lastk, lastv, startk = None, None, None
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        if int(v) > n:
            if startk is not None:
                interval.append(int(d[k]))
                result[(startk, k)] = interval
                interval = list()
                startk = None
        else:
            if lastv:
                interval.append(int(d[lastk]))
                startk = lastk
            interval.append(int(d[k]))
        lastk, lastv = k, int(v) > n
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print intervals(d, 70)
```

When I run this it prints:

```
OrderedDict([((0, 43), [92, 70, 77]), ((61, 93), [77, 69, 67, 68, 87])])
```

which is the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

*sidenote: Your dictionary has string values, not int values. And you might mean <= rather than <, in your example.*

So to restate your problem more clearly, you:

- Have an ordered list of points `(x,y)`
- Have a threshold value T
- Wish to find all consecutive runs of points p<sub>i</sub>,...,p<sub>j</sub> such that the endpoints are >T but the other points are not; i.e. all stretches where the points "dip down into and out" of the threshold line. (**Note that such runs may overlap, e.g. `[71,70,{71],70,71}`**)

The algorithm would be as follows:

```
from itertools import *

def dippingIntervals(points, threshold=70):
    yBelowThreshold = lambda i: points[i][1]<=threshold

    for below,g in groupby(range(len(points)), yBelowThreshold):
        if below:
            interval = list(g)
            start,end = interval[0],interval[-1]
            if start>0 and end<len(points)-2:     #modify if "open" intervals also desired
                yield points[start-1 : end+2]
```

Demo:

```
>>> d = [(0, 92), (11, 70), (43, 77), (44, 76), (61, 77), (64, 69), (68, 67), (84, 68), (93, 87), (108, 81), (141, 74)]
>>> pprint(list( dippingIntervals(d) ))
[((0, 92), (11, 70), (43, 77)),
 ((61, 77), (64, 69), (68, 67), (84, 68), (93, 87))]
```

You can post-process the data without much hassle, for example to get it into the format you wanted, modify the above function like so:

```
... yield (start,end), {xy[1] for xy in points[start-1 : end+2]}
```

The downside of this method is that it doesn't work on iterators; the following would work on iterators, and is more "classic" way of doing it:

```
def getY(point):
    return point[1]

def dippingIntervals(points, threshold=70, key=getY):
    """
        Returns runs of points whose y-values dip below intervals
        >>> list( dippingIntervals([71,70,74,64,64,70,71], key=lambda x:x) )
        [(71, [70], 74), 
         (74, [64, 64, 70], 71)]
    """
    def match(point):
        return key(point)<=threshold

    lastP = None
    for p in points:
        if lastP==None:
            lastP = p
            continue

        if not match(lastP) and match(p):
            start = lastP
            R = [p]
        elif match(lastP) and match(p):
            R += [p]
        elif match(lastP) and not match(p):
            end = p
            yield start,R,end

        lastP = p
```

Comment: Thanks! So do I want to create a dictionary with tuples instead of how I have it now? That is, d = {0: '78', 35: '61.33330154', 172: '65', 110: '59.66669846'} should be d = [(0,78),(35,61.33330154),(172, 65), (110, 59.66669846)]? I'm fairly new to Python and haven't come across this.

Comment: @LillianMilagrosCarrasquillo: this is not necessary, as you can merely iterate over your dictionary like so: `d.items()`, which returns an iterator over `(key,value)` pairs in your list as tuples. So `dippingIntervals(d.items())`. Note that the order returned is arbitrary, but in your case you're using an ordered dictionary. I personally would have avoided using strings in the first place, but if it's too late to change that, you can do `d = {k:float(v) for k,v in d.items()}`.

Comment: thanks. I'm trying some other possible d's and am getting something weird. Any thoughts on what's going on?

***********************

>>> c = {k:float(v) for k,v in d.items()}>>> c{0: 78.0, 35: 61.33330154, 172: 65.0, 110: 59.66669846}
>>> a = list(dippingIntervals(sorted(c.items())))>>> a
[]

Comment: @LillianMilagrosCarrasquillo: yes, this is what I referred to in my comment `#modify if "open" intervals also desired`. When you defined the problem statement, you specifically excluded intervals that "trailed off the ends" of your list of points. For example, you specifically excluded intervals where the left boundary and right boundary are undefined. It you want those intervals after all, you can modify either algorithm by tacking on `None` to the ends of the list, and modifying the logic a tiny bit.

Comment: e.g. to modify the first algorithm, make `yBelowThreshold = lambda i: False if None else points[i][1]<=threshold`, `points = [None]+points+[None]`, and you can delete the `if` statement.

Comment: @ninjagecko, the groupby solution is really smart; +1. But see the last part of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9611759/577088) for a way to make it iterator-friendly.

Comment: @senderle: Cute, the triplet idea was exactly how I was going to implement it to be iterator-friendly. But I thought it would have been uglier; I didn't think to use `set`. I don't so much mind converting the iterator to a list first actually, was thinking that this problem might benefit from being stream-friendly.